# Is it possible to use prefixes for template definition in RML/SPARQL mapping?

Tags: sparql, rml-rdf

I'm trying to map tabular data into RDF using [RML mapping](https://rml.io/specs/rml).

I've figured out how to define and use prefixes for `rr:constant` definitions as indicated with the `<<---` arrows in the code below. I've also figured out how to map column values using `rr:template`, as indicated with the `<<<<<<` arrow in the same code.

```
@prefix rr: <http://www.w3.org/ns/r2rml#>.
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>.
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/>.
[...]
:map_001 rr:predicateObjectMap [
             rr:predicate rdf:type; # <<---
             rr:objectMap [
                 rr:constant ex:MyClass; # <<---
                 rr:termType rr:IRI 
                 ]
             ];
         rr:predicateObjectMap [
             rr:predicate ex:myPredicate; # <<---
             rr:objectMap [
                 rr:template "http://example.org/{some_column}" # <<<<<<
                 ]
             ].
```

My question is: is it possible to somehow use prefixes in `rr:template` definitions, in order to not have to explicitly write the complete base URI? For example, I'd like to do something like what is shown below, although this clearly doesn't work:

```
:map_001 rr:predicateObjectMap [
             rr:predicate ex:myPredicate;
             rr:objectMap [
                 rr:template ex:"{some_column}" # <<--- DOESN'T WORK!
                 ]
             ].
```

Is there any syntax for this, or is it simply not possible?

Comment: that is unfortunately not possible, according to the R2RML specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/r2rml/#from-template - at least not via `rr:template` - not sure if there some other workaround, but I couldn't find anything in the specs.

Comment: Ok thanks. Feel free to add this as an answer instead of a comment, and if noone else comes up with a solution I'll accept it.